# Only one model in mongoose connection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I logged my connection and got this:

```
// Connect to Mongo
const promise = mongoose 
  .connect(db, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useFindAndModify: false }) // Adding new mongo url parser 
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...')) 
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 

  console.log(promise);
```

Here' what is logged:

```
Promise { <pending> }
NativeConnection {
  base: Mongoose {
    connections: [ [Circular] ],
    models: { user: Model { user } },
    modelSchemas: { user: [Schema] },
    options: { pluralization: true, [Symbol(mongoose:default)]: true },
    _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
    Schema: [Function: Schema] {
      reserved: [Object: null prototype],
      Types: [Object],
      ObjectId: [Function]
    },
    model: [Function],
    plugins: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ]
  },
  collections: {
    users: NativeCollection {
      collection: null,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'users',
      collectionName: 'users',
      conn: [Circular],
      queue: [],
      buffer: true,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    }
  },
  models: { user: Model { user } },
  config: { autoIndex: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false },
  replica: false,
  options: null,
  otherDbs: [],
  relatedDbs: {},
  states: [Object: null prototype] {
    '0': 'disconnected',
    '1': 'connected',
    '2': 'connecting',
    '3': 'disconnecting',
    '99': 'uninitialized',
    disconnected: 0,
    connected: 1,
    connecting: 2,
    disconnecting: 3,
    uninitialized: 99
  },
  _readyState: 2,
  _closeCalled: false,
  _hasOpened: false,
  plugins: [],
  id: 0,
  _listening: false,
  _connectionString: 'Sorry, but cannot pass :)',
  _connectionOptions: {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
    driverInfo: { name: 'Mongoose', version: '5.10.3' }
  },
  client: MongoClient {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    s: {
      url: 'sorry, but cannot pass :)', 
      options: [Object],
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
      dbCache: Map {},
      sessions: Set {},
      writeConcern: undefined,
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  '$initialConnection': Promise { <pending> },
  then: [Function],
  catch: [Function],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    open: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 1
```

The problem is that I have three models: post, user and message and because of that I cannot for example upload file with multer for message or post. Why is it happening? It cannot be a problem with my cluster, because I have second database on that cluster in other projects that works( which have implemented the same things, but with correct effect).

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I think can be happening with this connection you might be passing a new schema and model that you will see in your object is with that schema. You don't get all schemas from the cloud, the schema being returned is the one that exists with this connection.

Comment: support your answer with an example as asked in the question.